# genlock error on ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

My problem is the follow, I have all libraries up-to-date and all things(including on kernel) to get new Qualcomm ICS Adreno drivers working on ICS.

After my build, i get a known error on [logcat](http://pastebin.com/JUBfnhKL)(*) line 435.

My phone is an ARMv6 called Galaxy 5 or Europa.

Any help to solve any of the problems on logcat are welcome.

(*)

```
E/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): We support 2 buffers

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): using (fd=34)

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): id           = msmfb30_30001

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): xres         = 240 px

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): yres         = 320 px

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): xres_virtual = 240 px

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): yres_virtual = 640 px

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): bpp          = 32

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): r            = 24:8

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): g            = 16:8

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): b            =  8:8

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): width        = 38 mm (160.421051 dpi)

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): height       = 51 mm (159.372543 dpi)

I/msm7x27.gralloc( 4574): refresh rate = 0.00 Hz

D/CALCFPS ( 4574): DEBUG_CALC_FPS: 0

D/CALCFPS ( 4574): period: 10

D/CALCFPS ( 4574): ignorethresh_us: 500000

D/CALCFPS ( 4574): DEBUG_CALC_FPS: 0

D/CALCFPS ( 4574): period: 10

D/CALCFPS ( 4574): ignorethresh_us: 500000

D/FramebufferNativeWindow( 4574): mNumBuffers = 2

**E/libgenlock( 4574): genlock_create_lock: open genlock device failed (err=No such file or directory)**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a late reply, but it looks like your error stems from your kernel not having genlock built into the kernel. Have you backported/merged in the genlock device driver into the kernel?

Not sure what cpu you run but its obviously MSM/QCOM..

So here's a good starting point.

https://github.com/ikarosdev/triumph-kernel-msm7x30/commit/d382ea0e23631bfce889425c0c3d7889df57bfbf